# How can I forward 0.0.0.0/0 to another router without using static-route command?

Tags: ospf

hope everything is fine wherever you are.

Now here is my question. I have two routers, R1 and R2. And I want R2 to see 0.0.0.0/0 address from R1. But without using static-route command. Both routers are using OSPF. How could it be?

With static-route, it would be:

```
configure router static-route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop <destination ip address>
```

ps. System is ALU 775 SR. 
Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

From a quick perusal of the manual, the router doesn't seem to have the equivalent of the "default-information originate" command that Cisco routers have.

One alternative is to make R2 a totally stubby area, with R1 as the ABR.  It will then inject a default route into the stub area (R2).

I've never configured this router, so I don't want to attempt to give you configuration commands.  But [this manual](https://infoproducts.alcatel-lucent.com/cgi-bin/dbaccessfilename.cgi/9300740801_V1_7750%20SR%20OS%20Routing%20Protocols%20Guide%209.0R1.pdf) seems to cover it pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

The default route isn't propagated by OSPF by default. You need to explicitly inject it into your area.

Answer (score 2):

on R1 you need to put the below command under area configuration :

```
ospf 
  area area-id
  originate-default-route
```